# Simple abs function provides a syntax error in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare an absolute value in python(3.6) but it gives me a syntax error.

```
if (x1-x2) % 2 == 0 and abs(x1-x2)/2 == abs(y1-y2):
```

I have tried to reproduce it in the python console with

```
>>> x1 = 5
>>> x2 = -10
>>> abs(x2-x1)
15
```

as well as

```
>>> if 5 < abs(x2-x1):
...   print('hi')
...
hi
```

And yet in the code it returns an error.

This is the whole program so far:

```
def knight(p1, p2):
    x1 = int(coordinates(p1[0]))
    x2 = int(coordinates(p2[0]))
    y1 = int(p1[1])
    y2 = int(p2[1])
    if (x1-x2) % 2 == 0 and abs(x1-x2)/2 == abs(y1-y2):
        print abs(int(y1-y2))

def coordinates(t):
    if t == 'a': return 1
    if t == 'b': return 2
    if t == 'c': return 3
    if t == 'd': return 4
    if t == 'e': return 5
    if t == 'f': return 6
    if t == 'g': return 7
    if t == 'h': return 8
```

Note: I am working with integers.

Comment: Are you sure the problem's on the line you've shared, and not e.g. a missing parenthesis on the previous line? I can run that snippet locally without errors.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Please update the question with the real code and the full error traceback.

Comment: The only syntax error in that code is the missing parentheses after `print` if you're using python 3.

Comment: @sjaymj62 SyntaxError: invalid syntax. With ^ under abs.
Also the function is called with knight('a1', 'c1') parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Python 3, you will get the following syntax error:

```
    print abs(int(y1-y2))
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It should be:

```
print(abs(int(y1-y2)))
```

Comment: Thank you! @Aran-Fey was right too, for some reason i mixed up if statement with print and did not even double check it.